# How Can I Check For Create Access on UNC File Share In C#?

Tags: c#, file, io

This appears to pass even when I do NOT have write permissions.

```
FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, folder);
f.Demand();
```

Comment: read this for hints and or information otherwise google for the topic https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a621122-6bf3-48bb-88a9-d121ee5310dd/how-to-check-if-i-current-user-has-the-permisson-for-a-dir?forum=clr

Comment: Thanks.  After looking at this and testing, it appears the best way is unfortunately to "just do it" and handle the exceptions, especially when dealing with UNC shares.